# Mocking in Grails Spock integration testing

Tags: grails, spock, integration-testing

I have grails rest api application which internally calls external rest apis through service. I want to mock external api calling service while doing integration testcases. In integration testcases, I am posting request to application rest api. Since I am not able to mock the external API, it fails if external api is not reachable.
So how to mock the service which calls external APIs in integration test-cases.

Comment: Without any code how we can suggest where is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Include the URL to the external API in your configuration so you can mock it, let's say its configuration key is called `myConfigValue`. Install [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/junit-rule.html) and include a test server as a JUnit rule:

```
@Rule
WireMockRule mockServer = new WireMockRule(WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().port(9900))
```

Feed the mock server's URL into your test like described in [the Grails manual](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html):

```
static doWithConfig(c) {
    c.myConfigValue = "http://localhost:9900/"
}
```

Then use WireMock's API to validate external calls and stub the responses, e.g.

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/binary-body"))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
    .withBody(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 })));
```

Check their documentation on what is possible. There are alternatives to WireMock but none have worked so well for us.

Comment: As an alternative to WireMock, here's a blog post using another library, Ratpack, to test Grails 3 applications: http://kyleboon.org/blog/2015/07/18/stubbing-service-interactions-when-testing-microservices/